# Instagram API CORB

Tags: angular, instagram, instagram-api, cross-origin-read-blocking

My angular app uses https://api.instagram.com/oembed to embed instagram posts, but it receives Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response, though  the app uses Jsonp.

The Chrome Console shows that the url is [https://api.instagram.com/oembed/?omitscript=true&omit_script=true&callback=**ng_jsonp**.__req0.finished&maxwidth=800&hidecaption=true&url=https://www.instagram.com/p/BeyU33KF-wQ/](https://api.instagram.com/oembed/?omitscript=true&omit_script=true&callback=__ng_jsonp__.__req0.finished&maxwidth=800&hidecaption=true&url=https://www.instagram.com/p/BeyU33KF-wQ/)

Comment: http.jsonp is undefined here, but I use import { Jsonp } from '@angular/http'; So, I work through Jsonp.

Comment: Though when I use just http (not jsonp) it works.

Answer (score 1):

JSONp is deprecated in Angular. And there is a pretty rational reason why. JSONp is a request method which was previously used to insert a callback into the response body of the request. You can think of it as a solution predating the wide accepted us of promises and observables in angular.

https://angular.io/api/http/Jsonp

From your example if working JSONp would be executing **ng_jsonp**.__req0.finished() when the response was received. The problem from an angular perspective is what if I am controlling the api you are requesting from. Well I could 301 your request to a different url with my own callback that contains malicious code.

This is the type of vulnerability that CORB is attempting to solve on behalf of the user.

This is also why the same request works just fine with a standard GET because the callback is simply ignored in favor of the valid JSON.

if you have a specific callback you want to execute after the response comes in I suggest taking a look at RXJS.

(This answer assumes you meant Angular (current) and not AngularJs if you meant angular js you should look into promises)